# setcookie can't store json

Tags: javascript, php, json, cookies

I need to save a json string to a cookie. But the string is always url encoded.

The cookie(s) are read via javascript and must be recieved as json string that is NOT url encoded and I can't edit any of the js part.

```php
$cs_f11 = [
    'f11_a1_p117'=>'some data',
    'f11_a2_p118'=>'some data',
    'f11_a3_p119'=>'some data'
];
setcookie('cs_f11', json_encode($cs_f11), time()+86400, '/');
```

If I use setrawcookie() I get an error like this:

*Cookie values cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014' in […]*

The javascript is also writing json to the cookies but perfecly fine with all commas.

Is there ANY way to write a json string to a cookie non-encoded with PHP?

Comment: If your value can contain stuff like newlines, then it _must_ be encoded - otherwise you'd be violating basic HTTP "syntax" (a header ends with a newline.)

Comment: @CBroe the values are just simple words and numbers like "yes" or "12.4"

Comment: But the JSON encoding still adds characters that `setrawcookie` won't let pass. But I guess you could create the _whole_ `Set-Cookie: ...` header string yourself, and then just use `header` to send it to the client.

Comment: As CBroe said, and [per spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc6265.html#sane-set-cookie), a cookie value is "US-ASCII characters **excluding** CTLs, whitespace DQUOTE, **comma**, semicolon, and backslash". JSON uses commas a lot, so there's no real way to pass JSON of any complexity _without_ encoding it in some fashion, either URL, BaseXY or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with the help of header(), [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953583/setcookie-cant-store-json?noredirect=1#comment121861692_68953583).

```php
header ('Set-Cookie: cs_f1=' . json_encode($cs_f1) . '; expires=0; path=/;', false);
```